# AngularJS video issue

Tags: angularjs

I am studying AngularJS by looking at the website http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js/contents and downloaded the videos, then going through the examples on my computer.

Everything went well until the video codeschool_1329.mp4, otherwise called "Shaping_Up_With_Angular_JS_Level_2b".  The example works correctly when the logic for selecting the panels is in the HTML code, but when the logic is moved to a controller, it no longer works correctly.  Thus I have the relevant HTML code:

```
<section ng-controller="PanelController as panel">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li ng-class="{active:panel.isSelected(1)}">
      <a href ng-click="panel.selectTab(1)">Description</a>
    </li>
    <!-- Repeated for Specifications and Reviews -->
  </ul>
</section>
<div class="panel" ng-show="panel.isSelected(1)">
  <h4>Description</h4>
  <p>{{product.description}}</p>
</div>
<!-- Repeated for Specifications and Reviews -->
```

and for the JavaScript code I have:

```
app.controller('PanelController', function(){
    this.tab = 1;

    this.selectTab = function(setTab){
        this.tab = setTab;
    };
    this.isSelected = function(checkTab){
        return this.tab === checkTab;
    };
});
```

exactly as in the video.  The latter is with the Angular module and another Angular controller for the store.

With both Google Chrome and Firefox, when I click on the each of the tabs "Description", "Specifications" and "Reviews", the selected tab is highlighted, as in the video, albeit blue rather than dark purple, but the text that is supposed to be displayed below the selected tab does not show up at all.  It looks as if there is some type of a problem with the isSelected function in PanelController with ng-show="panel.isSelected(1)", etc. in the lower part of the HTML code, although it appears to work correctly with ng-class="{active:panel.isSelected(1)}" when the tab is highlighted.

This works correctly when the logic for this is in the HTML code, as I said above, but no matter what I can do, I am unable to get this to work correctly when the logic is in PanelController.

There must be something simple that I am missing, and would be grateful to get this sorted out - many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<section ng-controller="PanelController as panel">
  ...
</section>
<div class="panel" ng-show="panel.isSelected(1)">
```

Only the `section` element is controlled by the panel controller, but you're trying to use `panel.isSelected(1)` out of that section. So that can't work.

Put the `div` inside the `section`, or wrap everything with another `div` and move `ng-controller="PanelController as panel"`to that wrapping `div`.

Comment: Many thanks for your help; I wrapped everything in a div tag and moved ng-controller="PanelController as panel" to the tag and it worked immediately.  What you said is now obvious, but I'm still learning.